# Salesforce Sandbox cannot be used normally

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

After logging in, an error will be reported: check your Internet connection and try again. After entering the detailed page of record, the following components will report an error:
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Please [edit] your post to include more detail.  What happens after you close the error windows - do you see the normal home page?